# "Adapter deployment failed: Could not resolve placeholder" error in IBM MobileFirst 6.3

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm unable to read a property's value from worklight.properties file.

I added property as `publicProtocol=http` in wroklight.properties file and used the property in my adapter.xml as `<protocol>${publicProtocol}</protocol>` but I'm getting the following error:

> Adapter deployment failed: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'publicProtocol'

Comment: Are you sure you have redeployed your project `.war` file? `worklight.properties` is part of that, so that would need to be updated on the server for it to have a value of that to resolve.

Comment: Agreed, this would definitely happen in such a scenario. If, we're talking here about an external server. In a development server the .war is auto-updated, the adapter would require redeployment of course. You need to better explain the question.

Comment: our server is development server only. The adapter changes are getting reflected but worklight.properties are not changing. I redeployed the adapters also

Comment: Make sure then to Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server. Also make sure that in Eclipse you have the following option ticked: from the menu bar > Project > Build Automatically.

Comment: yeah I tried all those things but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me using  IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 6.3.0.00-20150214-1702

1. Created a new project with a HTTP adapter.
2. Added to server\conf\worklight.properties the following: `myCustomProperty=http`
   The server was automatically restarted
3. Changed adapters\myAdapter\myAdapter.xml as follows and re-deployed the adapter:

   ```
   - <protocol>http</protocol>
   + <protocol>${myCustomProperty}</protocol>
   ```

To verify that it worked I simply:

4. Right-click the myAdapter folder and selected Run As > Invoke MobileFirst Procedure and click on OK to invoke the default procedure.

A browser window opened with a successful invocation.

Comment: I created a sample project and able to use the properties from the properties file an myAdapter.xml file. But the same is not working in my previous project.

Comment: Upload your previous project so it could be inspected.